# Keeping a variable in pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a drop down menu, after selecting a value and clicking submit you're sent to another page with a table displaying query results retrieved using the value. The table uses pagination to split the results after 5 records with next and previous links, but when you click on the next page the value is lost and with it the results.

I tried using sessions,

In page.php

```
session_start();
$id =  $_GET['id'];
$_SESSION["selectedID"]  = $id;
include "table.php"
```

And in table.php

```
$selectedUserID = $_SESSION["selectedID"];
```

But it's not working, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you `session_start()` in table.php?

Comment: you may be overwriting your session with a blank id, you should check it exists first.

Comment: Sorry am a beginner, what do you mean "overwriting your session with a blank id, you should check it exists first"?

Comment: Is `$_GET['id']` still defined on the next page?

Comment: $_GET['id'] works on table.php initially but not when I click on another page in the table. What should I do to keep it working on all the table pages?

Comment: Without more code to see, it would be difficult to provide a concrete answer. You need to append `id=$_GET['id']` to your pagination links, like Next, Previous, etc., so that it persists on all pages.

Comment: Got it working, I set the session in it's own page after selecting the id, loaded page.php from there and retrieved the session in table.php which kept it through all the pagination links.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to put a `session_start();` in your table.php

Comment: I tried adding session_start() in table.php in the beginning but it didn't work, so I tried without it. Still doesn't work either way.

Comment: His session is already started in page.php before he includes table.php.

Answer (score 0):

first, I imagine you are using post method for your search/filter, that's not recommended (my opinion), use always get method, next, maybe this [pagination php](http://www.aprender-a-programar.com/paginacion-php) class can help you.

Regards